# Angular + cdnify

Tags: angular, gulp, gruntjs, cdn

I am from an AngularJS background, and the build process of an AngularJS app has a process called `cdnify`, which converts local URLs to CDN ones:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cdnify

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cdnify

Does Angular have this build step? Or is it not required anymore?

If CDNs are still relevant, how would I achieve this in Angular + `@angular/cli`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.25, you can accomplish this two ways.

- add a `"deployUrl"` key in your project's `angular-cli.json`
- pass a value with the `--deploy-url` flag to `ng build`

Source: [PR #3285](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3285/files)

Comment: Thank you! I will follow this open issue. I am hesitant to use this work around. it seems a little hacky

Comment: That's fair that you wouldn't want to jump on a workaround solution, though I wouldn't say its hacky because it comes from the official webpack documentation. In any case, hopefully the feature will land soon (its in review!) and I'll update this answer when when that happens.